# 500 ошибка сервера при Ajax запросе, laravel 5.4

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

[image: Лог с ошибкой в браузере]

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/insert 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Ошибка где-то в коде на php только не пойму где может неправильно принимаю данные и сохраняю их?

Если отправляю методом get, то ошибка `422`

`HTML`

```html
<div class="form_section">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <h2>Оставить комментарий</h2>
    <div class="form_section__item">
        <label for="form_section__item_input" class="form_section__item_desc">Ваше имя</label>
        <input name="form_section__item_input" id="form_section__item_input" class="form_section__item_input_name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Герасим">
    </div>
    <div class="form_section__item">
        <label for="form_section__item_textarea" class="form_section__item_desc">Ваш комментарий</label>
        <textarea name="form_section__item_textarea" id="form_section__item_textarea" class="form_section__item_input_text"></textarea>
        <input class="form_section__item_button" type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Отправить">
    </div>
</div>
```

`JS`

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
fetch_customer_data();
function fetch_customer_data(query = '')
{
    $.ajax({
    url:"{{route('search')}}",
    type:'get',
    dataType:'json',
    data:{query:query},
    success:function(data)
    {
    $('.search-list').html(data.name);
    }
});
}
    $(document).on('keyup','#search',function () {
        var query = $(this).val();
        fetch_customer_data(query);
    });
});
</script>
```

`PHP(LARAVEL 5.4)`

```php
public function insert(UserRequest $request)
{
    if($request->ajax())
    {
        $makeUser = new User();
        $makeUser->name = $request->get('name');
        $makeUser->text = $request->get('text');

        $makeUser->save();

        session()->flash('notif','Ваш комментарий успешно добавлен');

        return redirect()->route('show');
    }
}
```

Comment: Надо открыть лог ошибок и найти __детальное описание ошибки__.

Comment: Прикрепил скрин лога из браузера

Comment: Разговор идёт не только и сколько про логи из браузера, а для сервера, которые у Laravel находятся в storage/logs директории проекта.

Answer (score 0):

В корне проекта в файле .env установите для параметра APP_DEBUG значение true и вы сможете видеть в браузере расширенные ошибки работы вашего сервера.